# What is the meaning of master browser?

Tags: networking, lan

After using NetBScanner tool I found some systems with **master browser** ON .Can anyone explain the meaning and significance of **master browser** in this tool.

Comment: A detailed description can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Master_Browser).

Comment: @AFH That description is highly confusing for someone not on a domain, or just looking round their domestic subnet & wondering what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft describes it as the following:

> Determine if the master browser has the server's name in its list. The master browser is the first server in the chain of communication that must contain the missing server's name

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/188305

Additionally:

> The Master Browser is responsible for the browse list within its
>   respective subnet and portion of the domain on its subnet. The Domain
>   Master Browser is used to collect information from each of the Master
>   Browsers via the NetServerEnum API call. Once collected the list is
>   merged with the Domain Master Browsers list for its own subnet.

[Wikipedia - Domain Master Browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Master_Browser)

Comment: So what is the - missign server's name?

Comment: I would assume its the server's host name.  Which server it is entirely depends on your infrastructure